# Is it possible to see all of the event handlers for a channel in backbone radio?

Tags: backbone.js

I have recently upgraded from backbone.wreqr to backbone.radio, however my old code has some instances where I check for a channel's handlers using channel._wreqrHandlers[eventName]. Is there a function of parameter where I can view all of the current handlers in backbone.radio?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter was renamed to ._requests and it can be evoked in the same way.

Replacing the channel._wreqrHandlers[eventName] for channel._requests[eventName] results in the same behaviour